# ERPnext: How to use custom script in web form

Tags: erpnext

This script works great in the document but fails when used in the web form. Console logs “frm is not defined” (the error is marked on the frm in the second line, before “.page.wrapper…”). How should I modify it in order to adapt to a web form? I’ve tried using DOM by referencing it by id and using an onclick event but didn’t work.

```
frappe.web_form.after_load = () => {
     frm.page.wrapper.find(".a1").on("click", function(evt){ 
         frappe.web_form.set_df_property("a1", "options", "<img src=LINK>"); 
         refresh_field("a1"); 
         frm.set_value("r1", 1); 
         refresh_field("r1");
      });
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: this works: https://github.com/frappe/frappe/issues/12407#issuecomment-805349276

Answer (score -1):

When adapting a script for a web form in Frappe, it's important to note that the context and objects available in a web form can differ from those in a standard DocType form. Specifically, frm (the form object) is not directly available in the web form's context as it is in the standard form scripts.

To modify your script for a web form, you'll need to adjust how you reference the form and its elements. Here's an example of how you could adapt your script:
frappe.web_form.after_load = () => {
$(".a1").on("click", function(evt){

```
    frappe.web_form.set_value('r1', 1);
    
    frappe.web_form.set_df_property("a1", "options", "<img src='LINK'>");
    
    frappe.web_form.refresh_field("a1");
    frappe.web_form.refresh_field("r1");
});
```

};